# How to display which line search term is on in VS2010 Search Result window?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I do a CTRL+Shift+F in VS2010 and search for something I can only see in which file the term exist in the Find Result window. I think by default the file and the line where the term exists is displayed but I fiddled with the settings and now I can only see the file path which makes it harder to determine the relevance without clicking on the file, if there are many hits.

Anyone that knows which setting I am talking about because I cannot find it again.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do find and replace, there are **find options** and **result options**.
Under result options, uncheck **display file names only.**

Comment: just a brief note ... there is a drop at the top of the window find and replace, click the arrow down and select "find in files" in order to show result options (ctrl+shift+F is the quick way for it). in case you don't see result option on the window